# Norm of a cb-homomorphism restricted to a generating operator space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-spaces

Let $\mathcal A \subset B(H)$ be an operator algebra and $\varphi: \mathcal A \rightarrow B(K)$ a completely bounded homomorphism. Suppose $\mathcal M \subset \mathcal A$ is an operator space such that $\overline{\rm Alg}(\mathcal M) = \mathcal A$.

> > Does there exist a universal constant $C$ such that $$C \|\varphi|_\mathcal M\|_{\rm cb} \geq \|\varphi\|_{\rm cb}? $$

Comment: Chris, by "operator algebra", do you mean one which is unital? one which is SOT-closed? or just any norm-closed subalgebra?

Comment: @YemonChoi Just the norm-closed kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not even when $\cal A$ is commutative and $\phi $ is a multiplicative linear functional.  For example, given $0<a<1$ let ${\cal A} =C[a,1]$, let $\cal M$ be the linear span of the function $f(x) = x$, and let $\phi $ be pointwise evaluation at $a$.

Comment: Why is $1\in \overline{\rm Alg}(\mathcal M)$?

Comment: @ChrisRamsey Doesn't Weierstrass approximation allow us to approximate the function $t\mapsto \min(t/a, 1)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ by polynomials with zero constant coefficient? (I am writing this late at night so perhaps I have made a silly mstake)

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes! That is what I was missing.